# Is it possible to access class created inside a method?

Tags: java, function, class, variables

I have here Main class which is extended **JFrame**. Inside this I have a function `Stockmenuactionperformed` which is created inside another class stock. And my question is if there is any possibility how to access this class stock from another function.. (through) some accessible content (cause class stock is exntended **JPanel**)..??

```
public class MainApp extends javax.swing.JFrame{

private void stockMenuActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          

    if (tabbedpaneAgenda.indexOfTab("SKLAD") == -1)
    {
        ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(System.getProperty("user.dir")+"\\src\\pics\\stock.png");
        stock st = new stock(MainApp.this);


    }
    else {}

}    
private void acces_class(){
   this.getClass().asSubclass(stock);
  } 
}
```

Comment: I don't see any `Stock` class there.

Comment: Do you want to access the `class` or the `instance` of the class?

Comment: You mean you want to be able to use methods of Stock?

Comment: Stock class is here: stock st = new stock(MainApp.this), and I want to access Instance of this class, its components and functions. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class MainApp extends javax.swing.JFrame{
    private Stock st;

    private void stockMenuActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEventevt){  

        if (tabbedpaneAgenda.indexOfTab("SKLAD") == -1)
        {
            ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(System.getProperty("user.dir")+"\\src\\pics\\stock.png");
            st = new stock(MainApp.this);
        }
        else {}
    }    
    private void acces_class(){
        st.doSomething();
    }
```

Comment: Potential for a NPE here.

Comment: This is nice and standard, right answer, I know it, but class st is now created within the startup and it is in memory and taking some space, thats why I was asking if there is some chance to get some reference and create it with the function I wrote up.. but anyway thanks!

Comment: It is not taking that much space. You only create a reference.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to test java GUI design,
and in my knowledge, java GUI design should better be implemented with MVC (Model-View-Control) design pattern.
In the MVC mentioned above, you will separate your JPanel (which you put it in your view) and all the essential elements (which would be put and be able to change in your model).
Put your main function in Controller, which will instantiate your model and view, plus two adapters (as communicator between model and view).

In this case, you won't worry about the access to any inner class, because you will have adapters to access all type and all variables as you put them all in your Model.

Comment: Thats nice! But I'm not so skilled java programmer to handle by myself, thaks for the tip I will try to use "uncle google", anyway If you have time, It will be nice if you can lead me by some steps..